# Create database based on a mdf file and specify location to store new database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I create a database based on a mdf file. However I want to be able to store the database in a different directory.

I have,

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname ON (FILENAME = N'C:\sql_data\dbname.mdf')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How you can specifiy a different locations for your database files is explained on the [Technet page CREATE DATABASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) .

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname 
ON 
(NAME = dbname_data, FILENAME = 'C:\temp\dbname.mdf')
```

If you want to do this with an already existing mdf file then you probably need to use `FOR ATTACH`.

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname 
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\temp\test\dbname.mdf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

It will create a new log file for you if you don't specifiy a location for the log file.